# How do I change the header on a 2 column CSV file in python using the pandas library without creating a new file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am working on a data analysis project. The file *Data_Count.csv* has two columns and was created using the pandas `value_counts()` function. One of the columns has a heading while the other does not. How can I make it so both columns have the headings "Distance" and "Frequency" respectively without having to create a new file? Here is my code so far. Sorry, I am new to python so my code isn't that efficient.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  count = int(input("How many distance entries do you wish to record?: "))
  with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(calculate(count))

df = pd.read_csv("results.csv", header=None)
df.to_csv("results.csv", header=["Raw"], index=False)

df = pd.read_csv("results.csv")
ft = df["Raw"].value_counts(sort=False)
ft.to_csv('Data_Count.csv')
```

I want the final product to look like:

```
Distances       Frequency
1               1
2               3
3               2
4               1
5               2
```

It currently looks like:

```
             Raw
1            1
2            3
3            2
4            1
5            2
```

Furthermore, is it possible to somehow condense this code so that only one file is created instead of two (This is not important and doesn't have to be answered)? For reference, the calculate(count) function looks like:

```
def calculate(n):
    outputs = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
        
        if NUMBERS.index(num1) < NUMBERS.index(num2):
            difference = subtract(num1, num2)
            
        elif NUMBERS.index(num1) > NUMBERS.index(num2):
            difference = distance(num1, num2)
            
        else:
            difference = 0
        outputs.append([difference])
    
    return outputs
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) for set index name with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), last add `index=False` to `to_csv` for avoid write default `RangeIndex`:

```
ft = (df["Raw"].value_counts(sort=False)
               .rename_axis('Distances')
               .reset_index(name='Frequency'))
ft.to_csv('Data_Count.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Will that also produce the `Frequency` column name?